# Nuxt 3 useLazyFetch() blocks navigation

Tags: asynchronous, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxt3

I supposed that the `useLazyFetch` composable from Nuxt 3 shouldn't block navigation, however, in my case, it does.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```js
<template>
    <div v-if="!pending">
        {{ data }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        Loading
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const { data, pending } = useLazyFetch('/api/test')

</script>
```

this is what the test api endpoint looks like:

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('works')
        }, 2000)
    })
})
```

Comment: Hey there! How can you tell it is blocking the navigation?

Comment: It does. Try it (I just extended timeout to 5 secs to make it more obvious) https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-axmkyc?file=app.vue Unfortunately, I also dont know whats going on right now. I suggest you ask directly at Nuxt GitHub, if you didn't already - https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I figured it out.
If you don't want to have the initial request resolved on the server, you need to pass `server: false` to the options.
Example:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

const { data, pending } = useLazyFetch('/api/test', {
    server: false
})

</script>
```